# SendGrid : Is there any way to resend a email that has not been opened in last two days?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Is there is any way to resend a email using SendGrid API that has not been opened in last two days ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, if you've saved the message content, so that you can regenerate the message, and if you have their [Event Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html), so that you can know the open state of a particular message.

SendGrid doesn't keep message content for messages that are sent through their API, only their Marketing Campaigns. The Marketing Campaigns app *does* have "has not opened" logic, however.